# Get which host contains specific application on grafana templating

Tags: templates, filter, host, grafana, zabbix

I'm working with Grafana + Zabbix items, and I would like make an query like this:

- Search for an specific Zabbix application name on Grafana Templating
- Get what the host contains the application

Eg:

If I search on Templating:

```
*.*.Webmonitoring.*.
```

I can find something else:

> 'Download speed for scenario "a-site.com"' 
>   '"Download speed for scenario "other-site.com"' 
>   'Last error message of scenario "a-site.com"'
>   'Last error message of scenario "other-site.com"'

What I need is to know: How can I filter just the sites names using the query field?
Or better: How filter which hosts contains the mentioned application?

I can filter it using Regex field, but what I want will not works using this method.